# How can we retrieve Specific date format data from database through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, database

I am working with Javascript and for some requirement I need to connect oracle database and retrieve some data.

How can i read timestamp values from oracle database in java script please provide me the method or any help.

i have checked my database and the format  Is  "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,fffffffff"
How can i read this time stamp value.

Thanks

Lr

Comment: What database? What JavaScript environment (browser? nodejs? WSH? something else?)?

Comment: database is oracle and ie i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use oracle's datetime conversion when you select the data **TO_CHAR( *datetime*, *format* )**

like this you can get the datetime as a string from you db in any format you want and don't need to change the format later in Javascript.

see [Oracle Format Models](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)

simple example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MM:SS' ) AS TS FROM DUAL
```

or if you want only the time without date:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'HH24:MM:SS' ) AS TS FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

If in JavaScript you get a timestamp, then just use

```
new Date(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done through JavaScript.

You need a webservice that outputs the required data in a specific format (preferably JSON) and use AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to fetch it.